# Norms in quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

This should be well-known, but I can't find a reference (or a proof, or a counter-example...). Let $d$ be a positive square-free integer. Suppose that there is no element in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with norm $-1$. Then I believe that no element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ has norm $-1\ $
(in fancy terms, the homomorphism $H^2(G,\mathscr{O}^*)\rightarrow H^2(G,\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})^*)$, with $G:=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q})=$ $\mathbb{Z}/2 $, is injective). Is that correct? If yes, I'd appreciate a proof or a reference.

Comment: You might find the following paper useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1071

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is false. The smallest counterexample is $d = 34$. Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{34})$. The fundamental unit in $\mathcal{O}_{K} = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{34}]$ is $35 + 6 \sqrt{34}$, which has norm $1$, and therefore, there is no element in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ with norm $-1$.

However, $\frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{5} \sqrt{34}$ has norm $-1$, so there is an element of norm $-1$ in $K$.

Comment: Thanks very much to Jeremy Rouse for the nice answer, and to everybody else for the very enlightening comments.

Answer (score 18):

Jeremy Rouse already gave a counterexample, but let me expand on that somewhat. The question of whether $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ contains an element of norm $-1$ is purely local: this happens if and only if $d$ is a sum of two squares of rational integers. Indeed if we assume $d$ is square-free, this is saying that all odd primes dividing $d$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

The question of whether the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ contains an element of norm $-1$ is much more subtle, and is really a question about the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and the narrow class group. If we put $K_d = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and $\text{CL}(K_d), \text{CL}^\sharp(K_d)$ to be the class group and narrow class group of $K_d$ respectively, then the existence of an element of norm $-1$ in $\mathcal{O}_{K_d}$ is equivalent to $\text{CL}(K_d) \cong \text{CL}^\sharp(K_d)$. This is a subtle condition. One can simplify the criterion somewhat, since really only $2^\infty$-torsion matters. The simplified criterion is the assertion that $\text{CL}(K_d)[2^k] \cong \text{CL}^\sharp(K_d)[2^k]$ for all $k \geq 1$. The condition that $\text{CL}^\sharp(K_d)[2] \cong \text{CL}(K_d)[2]$ is equivalent to the field $K_d$ containing an element of norm $-1$, and is of course a necessary condition for the ring of integers to contain an element of norm $-1$.

Edit: I should emphasize that asymptotically the sets
$$S_1 = \{d : K_d \text{ contains an element of norm } -1\}$$
and
$$S_2 = \{d : \mathcal{O}_{K_d} \text{ contains an element of norm } -1\}$$
do not have the same density, hence there are infinitely many counterexamples. This is proved by Fouvry and Kluners in [this paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2010/172-3/p13). In the same paper they also mention that one expects an asymptotic formula for the density of $S_2$, given by Stevenhagen.

Comment: When you say in the 1st paragraph "if and only if $d$ is a sum of two squares" it's worth clarifying *where* it is a sum of two squares, or more to the point that it is the same in $\mathbf  Z$ as in $\mathbf Q$: an integer that is a sum of two rational squares is a sum of two integral squares. The setting of the OP's question is about solving an equation in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ or in its ring of integers, so it's nice to know this distinction does not occur for $n=x^2+y^2$ in $\mathbf Q$ and in $\mathbf Z$. You have a typographical error with $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-d})$ in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @KConrad thanks for the comment! I have fixed these two issues and also added an explanation that there are infinitely many counterexamples to the claim in the question.

Comment: References for the first paragraph: Hasse's norm theorem (or the Hasse-Minkowski theorem for ternary quadratic forms) combined with basic properties of the Hilbert symbol (cf. Ch.III in Serre: A course in arithmetic).

Comment: Actually one can see directly the following reciprocity phenomenon: $-1$ is a norm from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ if and only if $d$ is a norm from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$. Indeed, both statements are equivalent to $x^2+y^2-dz^2$ having a nontrivial zero over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now $d$ is a sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only it is a sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}$, so one can do without the references in my previous comment. This observation also resonates with KConrad's comment.

Answer (score 5):

Dirichlet's version of Gauss composition is in the book by Cox, (page 49 in first)  with a small typo corrected in the second edition.
For our purpose, duplication, it has a better look to equate $a=a'$ from the start, with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ sufficing,
$$ \left( ax^2 +bxy+ acy^2 \right)  \left( aw^2 +bwz+ acz^2 \right) = c X^2 + b XY + a^2 Y^2 $$
where
$$  X = axz + ayw+byz \; \; , \; \; \;  Y = xw - c yz  $$
so that the square of $\langle a,b,ac \rangle$   is $\langle c,b,a^2 \rangle.$

Today's question concerns $c=-1$

$$ \left( ax^2 +bxy -ay^2 \right)  \left( aw^2 +bwz -az^2 \right) = - X^2 + b XY + a^2 Y^2 $$
where
$$  X = axz + ayw+byz \; \; , \; \; \;  Y = xw + yz  $$
so that  $$\langle a,b,-a \rangle^2 =   \langle -1,b,a^2 \rangle.$$
We also see Stanley's fact that the discriminant is the sum of two squares,  $b^2 + 4 a^2$ the way I wrote things.

By the Gauss theorem on duplication, $  \langle -1,b,a^2 \rangle$ is in the principal genus

Furthermore, we now know that  the principal form is $SL_z \mathbb Z$ equivalent to
$$  \langle 1,b,-a^2 \rangle  $$
The principal form may not integrally represent $-1$ but does so rationally.

As to being in the same genus, we can use Siegel's definition of rational equivalence without essential denominator.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0  & 1 \\
 -a^2 & -b \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & \frac{b}{2} \\
 \frac{b}{2} & -a^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & -a^2 \\
 1 & -b \\
\end{array}
\right) = \; a^2 \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -1 & \frac{b}{2} \\
 \frac{b}{2} & a^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 b  & 1 \\
 -a^2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -1 & \frac{b}{2} \\
 \frac{b}{2} & a^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 b & -a^2 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \; a^2 \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & \frac{b}{2} \\
 \frac{b}{2} & -a^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$